# How do I download a file in a foreach loop using the Node.js via Request or HTTP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, download

I have an array of strings that are links to a URL that I would like to download content from. The downloadLinks array looks like:
`['stackoverFlow.com/File0', 'stackoverFlow.com/File1', 'stackoverFlow.com/File2']`.

Here is the code that I am using to try and download these files. Example code for both using Request and HTTPS.get

```
var fs = require ('fs');
var sleep = require('sleep');
var https = require('https');
var request = require('request')

// Using Request: 
var uniqueDownloadLinks = [ ...new Set(downloadLinks)]

for (downloadLink in uniqueDownloadLinks) {
    const download = (url, callback) => {
        request.head(url, (err, response, body) => {
            var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
            var dest = 'files/' + response.headers['content-disposition'].toLowerCase().split('filename=')[1].split(';')[0].replace(/"/g, '');
            request(url)
                .pipe(file)
                .on('close', callback)
        })
    }

    download(uniqueDownloadLinks[downloadLink], () => {
        console.log('fileDownloaded')
    })
    sleep.sleep(5);
}


// Using HTTPS.get
var uniqueDownloadLinks = [ ...new Set(downloadLinks)]

for (downloadLink in uniqueDownloadLinks) {
  var download = function(url) {
      var request = https.get(url, function(response) {
        var dest = 'files/' + response.headers['content-disposition'].toLowerCase().split('filename=')[1].split(';')[0].replace(/"/g, '');
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function() {
          file.close();
        });
    });
    download(downloadLink);
    sleep.sleep(5);
}
```

I have tested this code outside of the foreach loops in a test.js file including only the code to download a file and it works. The files output, everything is happy. When I try to download using the foreach loops I do not download anything. I suspect this has to do with me trying to download inside of a foreach loop but it is difficult to debug what is going wrong because I never enter the request code (For example trying to use `console.log(dest)` to output the destination + filename from the content-disposition header.

What should I do to be able to iterate over this array of links, and download each file?

Comment: sleep is awful, never use it unless you know what you do. Use request-promise and async..await instead of callback-based apis.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment made by Estus Flask I looked into the problem with using sleep and determined that he was correct in his assessment that "sleep is awful".

The fix to this involves making the download function async and using a promise to handle the sleep of 5 seconds.

```
async function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
await sleep(5000)
const $ = await download(uniqueDownloadLinks[downloadLink], () => {
  console.log('fileDownloaded')
})
```